# RESTkit with Xcode 4.5: libRestkit.a is always red

Tags: objective-c, restkit, xcode4.5

I'm a newbie to Xcode and I am trying to add RESTkit to an Xcode project I'm working on. I followed the instructions here https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x religiously and still all the time the RestKit static library libRestKit.a is always red indicating the file is not there. I tried looking for the file and adding it manually but it's not there. This happens both when I install RestKit via github (terminal) or when I download it from their website.

Help please

Answer (score 6):

Although this is purely aesthetic, the red labeling of frameworks and products is a common issue with Xcode. They are marked red because the file that this item refers to does not exist.

Take a look at the `File Inspector` in the Xcode window at the right. Below `Identity and Type` it says `Full Path`. This points to a build folder that probably doesn't exist or at least does not contain `libRestKit.a`.

Now set the `Location` to `Relative to Group`. Usually, this fixes the problem, because it will now look in the correct build folder, taking into account the target and active schema.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was just worried that this might affect the actual functionality of the app/code. As you said it is just aesthetic

Comment: I tried this but I could not change the drop down, it's inactive.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when i changed to "Absolue Path" and i dint added Link Libraries & target Dependency